# Swift run multiple block of codes asynchronously in background thread in order

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch

Is this code below guaranteed to run in order if it's on the same thread? If not, is there way to make sure that the asynchronous background tasks are performed in order?

```
DispatchQueue.global().async {
  print("a")
}
DispatchQueue.global().async {
  print("b")
}
```

Comment: If you want them run one at a time, create a serial queue.

Comment: `async` tasks will start in the order their enqueued, but on concurrent dispatch queues, they'll progress concurrently and finish in an undefined order.

Comment: If I want a code that doesn't block the UI, can I just run on some DispatchQueue(label: "a").sync?

Answer (score 2):

`DispatchQueue.global()` is a concurrent queue which means any 2 tasks will run in parallel whatever 1 ends the first

if you need to run them serially then either chain them one after the other or create a custom serial queue and dispatch the tasks in it like

```
let serialQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "queuename")
serialQueue.sync { 
   // task 1
}

serialQueue.sync { 
  // task 2     
}
```

Comment: Where is no need to lock the thread where you have initialised the DispatchQueue while the queue is serial. serialQueue.async { ... } will have the same result with not locking the parent thread

Comment: 2 additional questions based your comment. 1: If I use same label, is that sufficient to run in order or do I need to store the DispatchQueue with label and use it elsewhere? 2: Since it's a separate thread, Can I assume that it will not block the main thread, such as UI?

Comment: @dtails 1- every queue var runs his own tasks serially so if you created 2 then don't wait for a serial order between their separate tasks 2- sure this won't block the main thread

Comment: @Dmitriy inside the queue created in answer no difference between `sync ` and `async ` tasks will run serially and won't affect the main thread anyway

Comment: @Sh_Khan,Calling sync will always lock the parent thread while its execution.  [sync(execute:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchqueue/1452870-sync) "Unlike dispatch_async(_:_:), this function does not return until the block has finished".

Answer (score 1):

Just do them in order in the same async code.

```
DispatchQueue.global().async {
  print("a")
  print("b")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create your OperationQueue with 1 concurrent operation in the same time and any qos you need like this:

```
var operationQueue: OperationQueue = {

    let operation = OperationQueue()
    operation.qualityOfService = .userInitiated
    operation.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1

    return operation
}()

operationQueue.addOperation {

}
```

So you can use any quality of service and it's guaranteed to run in order you pass it inside operation queue but not guaranteed finish in order.

Answer (score 0):

DispatchQueue are a level of abstraction above an actual Thread. The benefit of this is that Apple can essential decided whether an actual operating system Thread is necessary depending on a few factors:

- The Operating System: watchOS, iOS, macOS, tvOS, etc...
- The Hardware: Watch Series 1 vs Mac Pro vs iPhone SE, etc...
- Power Constraints, CPU, etc...

Therefore, GCD basically gives the OS the ability to create a thread if it sees that as efficient for the user experience and the hardware the app is running on.

In the end, with the `.async` method each operation will **start** in order but each following operation **will not wait for the previous to finish**.

You can read more about [how each API works in relation to asynchronous development here.](https://learningswift.brightdigit.com/asynchronous-multi-threaded-parallel-world-of-swift) There's specifically a section on GCD which focuses the various flags and types of queues.